# WinUSB template is missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, usb-drive, winusb

I want to experiment with usb drivers on c++. I'm using visual studio express 2013 and I could not find WinUSB template. I have seen this [guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn376872(v=vs.85).aspx). However it is for visual studio ultimate/pro 2012. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I presume you meant guide, not globally unique identifier?  Anyway, try with the Community Edition instead of Express Edition.

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing. I am not able to find this template in VS 2010!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/dn433227)

> For building Windows 10 driver samples, Visual Studio Community 2015 works with WDK 10 to build samples from the samples gallery. Visual Studio Community 2015 is available free.

This contradicts some other pages (e.g. [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn376872(v=vs.85).aspx)) which say you need Visual Studio Professional or Ultimate. But it is wrong - I just downloaded VS 2015 Community, and [the Windows Driver Kit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/dn433227), and it installed fine and has a WinUSB sample.